# Xamarin.Forms App.xaml MergedDictionaries - StaticResource Lookup Not Detecting Styles

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am creating an application which will later go to the Play Store. The application is well-organised and tidy - and utilises the MVVM pattern.

In my application - I have a folder titled 'Styles' which contains numerous styles for different elements of my application:

[image]

As you can see I have a ResourceDictionary for a floating action button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                    xmlns:FAB="clr-namespace:Refractored.FabControl;assembly=Refractored.FabControl"
                    xmlns:rsvpapp="clr-namespace:RSVPApp"
                    x:Class="RSVPApp.Styles.FloatingActionButton">

    <Color x:Key="FAB_BlueNormalStyleColor">
        #0BA1D8
    </Color>

    <Color x:Key="FAB_BlueRippleStyleColor">
        #21B7ED
    </Color>

    <Color x:Key="FAB_BluePressedStyleColor">
        #3DCBFF
    </Color>


    <Color x:Key="FAB_RedNormalStyleColor">
        #CF0000
    </Color>

    <Color x:Key="FAB_RedRippleStyleColor">
        #ED2121
    </Color>

    <Color x:Key="FAB_RedPressedStyleColor">
        #FF3D3D
    </Color>

    
    <Color x:Key="FAB_OrangeNormalStyleColor">
        #FFA500
    </Color>

    <Color x:Key="FAB_OrangeRippleStyleColor">
        #EDA621
    </Color>

    <Color x:Key="FAB_OrangePressedStyleColor">
        #FFBB3D
    </Color>


    <Color x:Key="FAB_GreenNormalStyleColor">
        #00E500
    </Color>

    <Color x:Key="FAB_GreenRippleStyleColor">
        #69FA69
    </Color>

    <Color x:Key="FAB_GreenPressedStyleColor">
        #85FF85
    </Color>

    <!--Blue-->
    <Style x:Key="FAB_BlueRegularStyle"
           TargetType="FAB:FloatingActionButtonView">
        <Setter Property="ImageName"
                Value="ic_add_white.png" />

        <Setter Property="ColorNormal"
                Value="{StaticResource FAB_BlueNormalStyleColor}" />

        <Setter Property="ColorRipple"
                Value="{StaticResource FAB_BlueRippleStyleColor}" />

        <Setter Property="ColorPressed"
                Value="{StaticResource FAB_BluePressedStyleColor}" />

        <Setter Property="HasShadow"
                Value="True" />

        <Setter Property="IsVisible"
                Value="True" />
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="FAB_BlueMiniStyle"
           TargetType="FAB:FloatingActionButtonView"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource FAB_BlueRegularStyle}">
        <Setter Property="Size"
                Value="Mini" />
    </Style>

    
    <!--Red-->
    <Style x:Key="FAB_RedRegularStyle"
           TargetType="FAB:FloatingActionButtonView"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource FAB_BlueRegularStyle}">
        <Setter Property="ColorNormal"
                Value="{StaticResource FAB_RedNormalStyleColor}" />

        <Setter Property="ColorRipple"
                Value="{StaticResource FAB_RedRippleStyleColor}" />

        <Setter Property="ColorPressed"
                Value="{StaticResource FAB_RedPressedStyleColor}" />
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="FAB_RedMiniStyle"
           TargetType="FAB:FloatingActionButtonView"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource FAB_RedRegularStyle}">
        <Setter Property="Size"
                Value="Mini" />
    </Style>

    
    <!--Orange-->
    <Style x:Key="FAB_OrangeRegularStyle"
           TargetType="FAB:FloatingActionButtonView"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource FAB_BlueRegularStyle}">
        <Setter Property="ColorNormal"
                Value="{StaticResource FAB_OrangeNormalStyleColor}" />

        <Setter Property="ColorRipple"
                Value="{StaticResource FAB_OrangeRippleStyleColor}" />

        <Setter Property="ColorPressed"
                Value="{StaticResource FAB_OrangePressedStyleColor}" />
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="FAB_OrangeMiniStyle"
           TargetType="FAB:FloatingActionButtonView"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource FAB_OrangeRegularStyle}">
        <Setter Property="Size"
                Value="Mini" />
    </Style>


    <!--Green-->
    <Style x:Key="FAB_GreenRegularStyle"
           TargetType="FAB:FloatingActionButtonView"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource FAB_BlueRegularStyle}">
        <Setter Property="ColorNormal"
                Value="{StaticResource FAB_GreenNormalStyleColor}" />

        <Setter Property="ColorRipple"
                Value="{StaticResource FAB_GreenRippleStyleColor}" />

        <Setter Property="ColorPressed"
                Value="{StaticResource FAB_GreenPressedStyleColor}" />
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="FAB_GreenMiniStyle"
           TargetType="FAB:FloatingActionButtonView"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource FAB_GreenRegularStyle}">
        <Setter Property="Size"
                Value="Mini" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Now - I want to merge all of my resource dictionaries into my  app.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:styles="clr-namespace:RSVPApp.Styles"
             x:Class="RSVPApp.App">
    <!--
        Define global resources and styles here, that apply to all pages in your app.
    -->
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <styles:FloatingActionButton />
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            </ResourceDictionary>
            <Color x:Key="Primary">#2196F3</Color>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                    <VisualStateGroupList>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#332196F3" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateGroupList>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>        
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

As you can see - at the top I have declared a merged dictionaries attribute and inside I have the appropriate resource dictionaries.

In one of my pages - I decided that I would want to test whether the styles are detected:

```
    <fab:FloatingActionButtonView Style="{StaticResource FAB_BlueRegularStyle}"/>
```

Whenever I build the application - it immediately crashes because it cannot detect the style.

Maybe I am doing something wrong? I am not entirely sure. I am looking for a solution to this.

Thank you,

Comment: Could you please add the exact message of the exception you are getting? I copied your code in a blank project and modified trivial things (i changed FloattingActionButtonView for a Button and changed the style accordingly), and the style is being read correctly on my side...

Answer (score 0):

I created a test [project](https://github.com/tuke307/Samples/tree/master/Xamarin.Forms.Test) and tried to resolve your problem. I couldnt find heavy problems. I also commented the line where you specify the image source. Here are my results, I found about your problem;

## thoughts

at first, instead of

```xml
<Style x:Key="FAB_BlueRegularStyle"
TargetType="FAB:FloatingActionButtonView">
...
</Style>
```

use this;

```xml
<Style x:Key="FAB_BlueRegularStyle"
TargetType="{x:Type FAB:FloatingActionButtonView}">
...
</Style>
```

You profit from that.

## test result

here is my result from the emulator and the compiler.
[image: result]

## potential mistakes

Maybe you declared something wrong in your `.csproj` file, because in the following picture I cant see an arrow to see the xaml.cs file. In the `Styles_FloatingActionButton.xaml` file you point to the `FloatingActionButton` class declaration. Do you really have this file?
[image: this]

Maybe recreate your resource dictionary and check your file properties. It should look like this.
[image: style]

Answer (score 0):

Remove one ResourceDictionary level.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

In my project I use CSS files like below. You can then set a lot (not all) properties using CSS.

Here's more information on the subject: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/css/

Here's what it looks like far from finished though:

[image]
[image]
[image]

This file is called Main.css and it is in a 'css' directory:

```
* {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

body{
}

.StackLayout
{
    padding: 0;
}

Button {
    background-color: darkslateblue;
    color: white;
    font-size: 10;
    margin: 1;
    border-radius: 5;
}

Button.Delete {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}

Editor {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    min-height: 300;
}

Entry {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}

Label {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}

TabbedPage {
    BarBackgroundColor: black;
    color: white;
}

.WordContainer {
}

StackLayout.TitleViewBack {
    background-color: #2296f3;
}

Label.TitleView {
    font-size: 30;
    background-color: #2296f3;
    color: wheat;
}

.ToolbarTitle {
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
}
```

In my App.xaml I use the following. The stylesheet is now available for all xaml forms.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<tgb:TxfApplication
    xmlns:forms="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Forms.Views;assembly=MvvmCross.Forms"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:tgb="clr-namespace:TGB.Xamarin.Forms;assembly=TGB.Xamarin.Forms"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:eTabber.Views"
    xmlns:css="clr-namespace:XamlCSS;assembly=XamlCSS"
    x:Class="eTabber.App">
    <tgb:TxfApplication.Resources>
        <StyleSheet Source="/css/Main.css" />

        <views:TitleView x:Key="MainTitleView"/>

        <Style TargetType="ContentPage" x:Key="TitleView">
            <Setter Property="NavigationPage.TitleView" Value="{StaticResource MainTitleView}"/>
        </Style>
    </tgb:TxfApplication.Resources>
</tgb:TxfApplication>
```